# Displaying Data in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I would like to know how to display the JSON data return from the server into the GridView.
I had deserialized the JSON data and stored in a variable, but not able to display the data in Grid.
So please can one help me out to display the data in Grid.
**MY CODE:**

```
protected void btn_ShowCust_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
       {
          string url = clsGuid.GetAPI() + "/service/service/student/search/" + txtstuname.Text.Trim();
          HttpWebRequest reque = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
          reque.Method = "GET";
          reque.Accept = "application/json";
          reque.ContentType = "application/json";//application/x-www-form-urlencoded
          reque.UserAgent = "Java/1.6.0_22";
          reque.AuthenticationLevel =   System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
          reque.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abcd", "123456");
          reque.PreAuthenticate = true;
          reque.KeepAlive = true;
          reque.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic ERTGFEDCVTY=";


                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)reque.GetResponse();

          if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
              Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
              StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);

              using (var twitpicResponse = (HttpWebResponse)reque.GetResponse())
               {
                 using (var reader = new StreamReader(twitpicResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                  {
                     JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                     var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                     List<RootObject> myojb = js.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(objText);
                     DataTable dt = new DataTable();                                                                        
                     int countvalue = myojb.Count;                         

                     for (int i = 0; i < countvalue; i++)
                         {

                           //Need to display the data in GRIDVIEW...
                           //FirstName =dt.Rows.Add(myojb[i].firstName).ToString();
                           //LastName = dt.Rows.Add(myojb[i].lastName).ToString(); 

                           and so on...
                         }
                     gvRecipient.DataSource = dt;
                     gvRecipient.DataBind();
                  }
              }

          }
      }
      catch
      {
        Msg.InnerHtml = "<div class='msg-error'>We are facing some technical issues in processing your request. We will make it up quickly. Please try after some time.</div>";
      }

}
```

**MY JSON DATA**

```
[{"firstName":"asdf","lastName":"qwer"...so on..}]
```

**My GRID**

[image]

**ERROR:**

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason, why you convert List<RootObject> to DataTable? You can assign myojb directly to GridView datasource

Comment: i tried that one.. but cant able to insert the value,so i changed to list..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to define the columns:

```
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof (string));
dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof (string));
```

Try this code

```
protected void btn_ShowCust_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string url = clsGuid.GetAPI() + "/service/service/student/search/" + txtstuname.Text.Trim();
        HttpWebRequest reque = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        reque.Method = "GET";
        reque.Accept = "application/json";
        reque.ContentType = "application/json";//application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        reque.UserAgent = "Java/1.6.0_22";
        reque.AuthenticationLevel =   System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
        reque.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abcd", "123456");
        reque.PreAuthenticate = true;
        reque.KeepAlive = true;
        reque.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic ERTGFEDCVTY=";


            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)reque.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);

            using (var twitpicResponse = (HttpWebResponse)reque.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(twitpicResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    List<RootObject> myojb = js.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(objText);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();      
                    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof (string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof (string));

                     int countvalue = myojb.Count;                         

                      for (int i = 0; i < countvalue; i++)
                        {

                            //Need to display the data in GRIDVIEW...
                            //FirstName =dt.Rows.Add(myojb[i].firstName).ToString();
                            //LastName = dt.Rows.Add(myojb[i].lastName).ToString(); 

                            and so on...
                        }
                      gvRecipient.DataSource = dt;
                      gvRecipient.DataBind();
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Msg.InnerHtml = "<div class='msg-error'>We are facing some technical issues in processing your request. We will make it up quickly. Please try after some time.</div>";
    }

}
```